# Adding querystring parameter to tt_news links in TYPO3 page

Tags: typo3, tt-news, typolink

I’m trying to add an additional querystring parameter to all links from tt_news plugins (displayList) on page.  I've tried this, but it isn't working.

```
plugin.tt_news {
  displayList {
  title_stdWrap.typolink {
    additionalParams.data = &myparameter=1
  }
}
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The link is related to the `<!--###LINK_ITEM###-->` marker and not the title
This marker is filled with plugin.tt_news.pageTypoLink but i'm not sure you can use additionalParams on it. If it does not work, try to add a generic marker!